# Julia - Array of UTF8 behavior

Tags: julia

I encountered a problem which I've solved, but why the solution works doesnt make sense to me

I had a function similar to this one

```
function testB(a::Array{AbstractString})
   println(a)
end
```

running it like so gave me

```
testB(convert(Array{UTF8String},["a","b"]))
ERROR: MethodError: `testB` has no method matching     
testB(::Array{UTF8String,1})
```

Note that Im not manually converting to UTF8 in reality, its for demonstration, in reality I have an AbstractString array, but when I fetch elements from it, they become UFT8

My solution reads in short

```
function testA{T <: AbstractString}(a::Array{T})
   println(a)
end
```

running this method gives

```
testA(convert(Array{UTF8String},["a","b"]))
UTF8String["a","b"]
```

Can anyone tell me why testA works but testB doesnt?
Also, is there a name for this `{T <: SomeDataType}` notation?

Answer (score 1):

While `UTF8String` is a subtype of `AbstractString`, `Array{UTF8String}` is *not* a subtype of `Array{AbstractString}` (no covariance). Hence your testB does not work. (But `testB(convert(Array{AbstractString},["a","b"]))` should work.)

Rationale for why it has to be like this: a function `f(x::Vector{AbstractString})` could e.g. `push!` a new `FooString` into `x` (assuming `FooString` is a subtype of `AbstractString`). Now if `x` was in fact a `Vector{UTF8String}`, that would fail.